# Monkey Patching Exception class and other builtin classes

Tags: python

Regardless of the Excpetion type, I would like to print a message whenever an exception occurs.

I tried the following:

```
class MyException(BaseException):
  def __init__(self, msg):
    super(BaseException, self).__init__(msg)
    print "Howdy", msg

__builtins__.Exception = MyException

try:
  raise IOError("world")
except Exception as e:
  pass
```

I expected "Howdy world" to be printed but instead I get nothing.

EDIT:

@helmut suggested using sys.settrace, the following code works as expected.

```
import sys

def trace(frame, event, arg):
    print event
    return trace

sys.settrace(trace)

def foo():
    raise Exception()

def bar():
    foo()

def baz():
    try:
        bar()
    except:
        pass

baz()

exit()
```

Too bad this is too slow for my use case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Why not monkey-patch?**

Let me explain why the projected approach is flawed. What happens when you assign `MyException` to `Exception` is that you change the global variable `Exception` within this module. All exception classes defined before this assignment or in different modules will not use it. They will use the original value instead. Since `IOError` is created during interpreter startup, your assignment has no effect on it. So if you were to monkey-patch the `Exception` class you would be overriding its methods. Most importantly you would be changing its `__init__` and `__new__` methods. Unfortunately that method is not supported and changing those attributes results in:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'exceptions.Exception'
```

So the approach to monkey-patch the interpreter will likely not work out.

**Alternative: tracing**

An alternative would be to write a function to be passed to `sys.settrace`. It is invoked for each function call and should return another tracing function if the particular call is to be traced. Various events are passed to the latter tracing function and one of them is `'exception'`. By filtering on those events you may already achieve the intended effect.

Comment: Hm is there anything lighter than settrace? This has slowed my program more about 100x.

Comment: Hm, I just wrote a test program to see if this would work and it doesn't seem to. It will print uncaught exceptions but not caught exceptions. I will add the example to the question.

Comment: Your example tracing function does not return function tracers, so you will not trace any bodies and thus miss all exceptions.

Comment: On a second thought, if you need more performance, you could try using PyPy. It should be able to deal with tracing better, because it uses a tracing JIT compiler, so your tracing function should quickly become a fast-path. It may also allow you to monkey-patch builtin classes.